# count items in each category

Tags: sql

I've the Following Table Schema for table Items

```
id | item_id | category_id
```

I've sample data in this table

```
id  | item_id | category_id

1   | 1       | 1
2   | 1       | 2
3   | 2       | 1
4   | 2       | 2
5   | 3       | 1
6   | 1       | 1
```

Requirement: I need to count all those items which are repeating in each category_id. In the above scenario item_id '1' is repeating in category '1'. I need to count the invalid or repeating item_id against each category_id.

Comment: You did not define what 'invalid' item_id means.

Comment: You can do something along the lines of `select count(*), category_id, item_id from table where true group by category_id, item_id` and then look for records with a count > 1. Performance on a large table would be terrible, though.

Comment: invalid means repeating, means these are same things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should do it for you:

```
Select item_Id, category_id
From Table
Group By item_Id, category_id
Having Count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT category_id, item_id, COUNT(*) 
FROM table
GROUP BY category_id, item_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

will give you repeating ones. As for 'invalid' you did not define what these are.